# Como quito con regex una linea que coincida con una string de un archivo txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, regex, filereader

Saben como quitar una linea(o renglón) especifica de un archivo .txt con python? necesito regex para eso?

```py
wordA = "bueno"
wordB = "malo"

elif (wordA in negative_words) and (wordB in negative_words):
            #Borra wordA en negative_words
            #La palabra B la deja como esta porque coincide con lo que le digo

            #BORRAR wordA
```

necesito algo asi
osea que si detecta la palabra wordA (que es un str) en un txt que ya contiene una lista de palabras colocadas cada una en una linea, de este modo:

```
hola
prenda
bueno
buenisimo
avion
salto
salmon
tecla
baile
vestido
auricular
```

si la palabra fuese `bueno`
la idea seria que quitase esa linea del txt, y quedase:

```
hola
prenda
buenisimo
avion
salto
salmon
tecla
baile
vestido
auricular
```

Siempre dejando esa ultima linea en blanco

Comment: Aquí no muestras ninguna regex

Comment: estaba pensando en guardar el contenido del txt en una variable como una string, y ahi ponerle alguna regex , pero me queda como mucho la linea en blanco en medio y eso rompe mi estructura de datos

Comment: voy a dar una respuesta pero sin usar expresiones regulares ya que no pones ninguna.

Comment: si queda reemplazado por la linea vacia el programa cuando revise esa lista fallará, por eso me estoy liando un poco. En caso de aplicar la regex con luego sobreescribir el archivo bastaria supongo

Comment: no quice porner el code porque es bastante extenso y siento que se pierde demasiado el sentido de la pregunta en si

Comment: siendo que la idea es abrir el archivo, supongo que combiene con w+ . Lueho hallar la palabra. Para luego borrar la linea de esa palabra y que no quede la linea en blanco.
Y por ultimo cerrar el archivo con los datos actualizados (no se si combiene sobreescribirlo o no, quizas poniendo a y no w ? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero recreamos tu archivo `txt`

```py
with open("archivo.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("""hola
prenda
bueno
buenisimo
avion
salto
salmon
tecla
baile
vestido
auricular""")
```

Ahora solo tenemos que leerlo por líneas con el método `readlines()` que devuelve una lista y con una simple comprensión de lista crearemos una lista con las lineas cuya palabra sea distinta de bueno.

```py
wordA = "bueno"
with open("archivo.txt", "r+") as f:
    lineas = [linea.strip() for linea in f.readlines() if linea.strip()!=wordA]
    f.truncate(0) #borramos el contenido del archivo
    f.seek(0) #nos movemos al inicio
    f.writelines("\n".join(lineas)) #volvemos a escribir el contenido
```

Si lo quieres hacer con expresiones regulares solo cambias la parte del `if` por algo como `if regex.match(linea.strip())`

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora lo estaba implementando y lo checo